# Close nth open window in IE11 using Selenium

Tags: selenium, automation

On the page "http://www.seleniumframework.com/Practiceform/" There is a button "New Message Window".

I want to hit this button 5 times which will open 5 windows. All the windows have same content. So cant identify specific window using content

i want to close the 3rd window.

Comment: Please update your question with the desired language.

Comment: I am trying it in Java

I have collected all the handles using getWindowHandles()
but i dont know how to go directly to third window.

Comment: You are already on the right path. `.getWindowHandles()` returns a collection. Switch to the third window in the collection. There is lots of reference material on this site and elsewhere on how to do that. Give it a try and if you get stuck, update this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only seeing this open the same window multiple times. However, if you want to do this, you would:

1. Get the current window handles
2. Switch to the third one
3. Send your webdriver instance the close command (not the quit command, that will close all windows)

Without knowing what language you're using, I won't be able to give you an example.